# Just few hours with Couchdb and... when I create a view how do get the key?

Tags: view, key, couchdb

I am trying to learn Couchdb and have a very very newbie question. I have following two documents

```
{
   "type": "type1",
   "code": "10",
   "name": "ten",
},
{
   "type": "type2",
   "code": "20",
   "name": "twenty",
}
```

I have created a view as following

```
function(doc) {
  emit(doc.type, {"code":doc.code, "name":doc.name});
}
```

The above function works fine but I would like to get the key instead of writing as following example which doesn't work:

```
function(doc) {
  emit(doc.type, {key(doc.code):doc.code, key(doc.name):doc.name});
}
```

How do I do that???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Simple solution

I'm not sure this is what you're after but you can do this:

```
function(doc) {
  emit(doc.type, doc);
}
```

Then all the fields (including `type` but also `_id`, `_rev`…) are available without having to type them explicitly.

#### Full solution

`key(doc.code):doc.code` does not look better than `"code":doc.code` to me, but if you really want to avoid duplication, you can do:

```
function(doc) {
  var elem = {}, keys = ["code", "name"];
  for (var i in keys) {
    elem[keys[i]] = doc[keys[i]];
  }
  emit(doc.type, elem);
}
```

It seems overkill unless you have a long list of keys.